# When Jquery Play Pause Audio Button Finish Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, playback

How can I make the audio go back to play after it's finished?

start button is: PLAY - is ok
click play start audio and button text is PAUSE - is ok
but after finish the audio, button must be back to PLAY TEXT

```js
$(".ttt").click(function() {
    if ($(".podcast-content audio").get(0).paused) {
      $(".podcast-content audio")[0].play();
      $(".ttt").html('Pause');
    } else {
      $(".podcast-content audio")[0].pause();
      $(".ttt").html('Play');
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#/" class="ttt">PLAY</a>

<div class="podcast-content">
      <audio>
      <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
      </audio>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the functionality aiming for as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".ttt").click(function () {
        if ($(".podcast-content audio").get(0).paused) {
            $(".podcast-content audio")[0].play();
            $(".ttt").html('Pause');
        }
    });
    $(".podcast-content audio").on('ended', function() {
        $(".ttt").html('Play');
     });     
})
```

```html
<html lang="">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-w   idth, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>p5.js example</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#/" class="ttt">PLAY</a>

<div class="podcast-content">
      <audio>
      <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
      </audio>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```